# How I/O tool test corruptions

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I am trying to understand how I/O tools like dt and FIO test data corruption. 
For example, say in 2G RAM system, dt or FIO writes 1G of data using some pattern and after writing 1G of IO it now has to see if the IO written is correct or corrupted so it reads back the 1G data that's written and determines data integrity.

My question is , how will dt or FIO know what it had written initially, I doubt if it would keep a copy of the original data

Would like to know how dt or Rio knows what was written initially.

Answer (score 1):

> How will dt or FIO know what it had written initially?

No needs to store all written data when you know the **pattern** used for write.

E.g., if the pattern was "write 1 into every byte", then you know that every byte after writing should contain 1.